# Using aggregate function in WHERE clause to UPDATE a table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables **employee** and **department**. They are linked with **dep_id** column, which is a primary key in **departments** and a foreign key in **employee**.

My goal is to:

***Update salaries of all employees whos salaries are above average salary in their department.***
Right now I have 2 queries to do this:

```
UPDATE employee E 
SET E.payroll = E.payroll + 1000
WHERE E.payroll > (SELECT AVG(E2.payroll) FROM employee E2 WHERE E.dep_id = E2.dep_id)
```

I get an error:  **#1093 - Table 'E' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data**

2) In **department** table I store the amount of employees per department and a total payroll they have per department

```
UPDATE employee E 
SET E.payroll = E.payroll + 1000
WHERE E.payroll > (SELECT department.dep_payroll / department.dep_amount FROM department  WHERE department.dep_id = E.dep_id)
```

This one works fine, but because I have a trigger which fires after\before (I checked both ways) updating **employee** table and updates dep_payroll it blocks me from executing 2nd query giving this error
**#1442 - Can't update table 'department' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**
Here it is

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t3` BEFORE UPDATE ON `employee`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE department
SET dep_payroll = dep_payroll - OLD.payroll + NEW.payroll
WHERE dep_id = NEW.dep_id
```

How can I execute an update query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-to-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)
The rules used to update MySQL database is the same, as it's standard T-SQL language.

Comment: @MaciejLos, I didn't see that one. But what about second query?

Comment: IIRC this is a flaw in MySQL. You cannot use the same table that you are updating in the where clause. However, it usually works when you get one level deeper; something along the lines of `WHERE E.payroll > (SELECT * FROM (SELECT AVG(E2.payroll) FROM employee E2 WHERE E.dep_id = E2.dep_id) x)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it's magical, thanks!  I'll post it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider a temporary table to store the list of employees to update. Then run the update itself in a separate query:

```
create temporary table list (emp_id int)
;
insert  list
select  emp_id
from    YourTable emp
join    (
        select  dep_id
        ,       avg(payroll) as avg_pay
        from    YourTable
        group by
                dep_id
        ) dep
on      emp.dep_id = dep.dep_id
where   payroll > avg_pay
;
update  YourTable
set     payroll = payroll + 1000
where   emp_id in (select emp_id from list)
;
```

[Example at regtester.](http://rextester.com/BZI32430)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's the most effective way to write such query, buy thanks to @ThorstenKettner I've managed to find the answer

```
UPDATE employee E 
SET E.payroll = E.payroll + 1000
WHERE E.payroll >
(SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT AVG(E2.payroll) FROM employee E2 INNER JOIN employee E ON E.dep_id = E2.dep_id) 
 X)
```

However, it still leaves the second part of my question unanswered.. Is it a flaw in MySQL or a trigger written wrongly?

Comment: Not sure why you have an `inner join` in the subquery, that would count a lot of employees multiple times. You're also not looking at the average salary for the department where the employee works: there's no link between the subquery and the row you're updating.

Comment: @Andomar, well, I was testing it on my sample database and it works